# My python script is runs pretty good on juyper lab, but doesn't on powershell of either anaconda or VS code

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, anaconda, jupyter

my file name runEveryXmin.py. When i run it on Jupyter lab, it runs. When i try to run it on anaconda powershell prompt or VS code terminal, it prints

Starting work schedule
sleeping for 3.494036 seconds

Then sript exits without entering loop of calling function schedule_next_run.

Here is my script.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep
import random


def schedule_next_run():
    sleep_time = get_sleep_time()
    t = Timer(sleep_time, do_work)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print(f'sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds')

def get_sleep_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    last_run_time = now.replace(minute=now.minute // 1 * 1, second=0, microsecond=0)
    next_run_time = last_run_time + timedelta(minutes=1)
    return (next_run_time - now).total_seconds()

def do_work():
    now = datetime.now()
    print('Doing some work at', now)
    sleep(random.uniform(0, 29))
    print('Work complete. Scheduling next run.')
    schedule_next_run()

print('Starting work schedule')
schedule_next_run()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well i shorted this out. All i had to do was to put blow line at the end of code. However i am not sure how it works. If anyone can explain, i would appriciate it.

Added this line at the end of code and it is working now.

```
input('Doing work every 5 minutes. Press enter to exit:\n')
```